# how make service start once android app turn on?

Tags: android, scheduling, android-service, android-alarms

i need to do something at the background but i need this service alive once the app turn on

although , i need to do at background always even the phone at sleep mode ??

i try to do service but this service after the phone go to sleep mode the service still alive but don't work what i attach to it.

using this

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService_Service.html

i see this   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396133/android-how-to-do-something-on-app-launch)  ,  **but i don't get the idea !!!**

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Myservice.class);
startService(intent);
```

If you do that in the onCreate method of your Activity then it will start the service as soon as your Activity is ran. From there, it should be running in the background. What is the issue your having?

Comment: this make the service on unless the phone at sleep mode ?

Comment: another thing at each oncreate the service will lunch again ?

Comment: Yes. Your service should be running if the phone's screen is off. And No, you can call startService(intent) as many times as you want and it will only create one instance of your service.

Comment: even this service contact with database on server ?

Comment: Yo man. Your service should be running in the background. No matter if it's accessing a database or consuming green eggs and ham