# SharedPreference does not store data once application restarts

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
public class CityPreference{
SharedPreferences prefs;

public CityPreference(Activity activity) {
    prefs = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public String getCity(){
    String defaultStr = "Helsinki,FI";
    return prefs.getString("city", defaultStr);
}

public void setCity(String city){
    prefs.edit().putString("city", city).commit();
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
   CityPreference cityprefs = new CityPreference(MainActivity.this);
    renderWeatherData(cityprefs.getCity());
```

How I change the String:

```
 private void showInputDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.change_city));

    final EditText cityInput = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    cityInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    cityInput.setHint("Helsinki,FI");
    builder.setView(cityInput);
    builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.submitBtn), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            CityPreference cityPref = new CityPreference(MainActivity.this);
            cityPref.setCity(cityInput.getText().toString());

            String newCity = cityPref.getCity();
            renderWeatherData(newCity);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

So, what i want to do is, when everytime I restart the app. It will always put

```
defaultStr to prefs.getString();
```

Should I clear the data Storage? or is there any better way to do that?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: i think you have to use getSharedPreferences instead of getPreferecnes(...)

Comment: getPreferences only work for single activity

Comment: I dont understand. Why do you use SharedPreferences if you dont want to keep the city when the app restarts?

Comment: You've not given any name to your SharedPreference file. Either give name, or use DefaultPreferences.

Comment: Please fix a little bit your question adding some context before the first piece of code and some lines about how & why the user is changing this value inside shared prefs.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of SharedPreference is wrong, Use `getSharedPreferences` instead of `getPreference()`, Also give name of your `SharedPreference`.

Try this out

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want default city value every time app started, just don't use shared preferences for that. Use loacal variable for city in your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Either use named file:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

OR use Default file:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other users are saying (see for instance @KulsDroid) answer, regardless of how you do read and init your Preferences you should change the way your application starts by adding a custom `Application` class to your project.

`Application` class has a method to override called `onCreate()` that you can use to perform useful things while the app loads and before the user is able to interact. So in your specific case you should invoke something like `CityPreferences.setCity(myDefaultCity)` inside that `onCreate()` method.

You can find official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and some related SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929562/register-application-class-in-manifest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396133/android-how-to-do-something-on-app-launch).

Also [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) is a good tutorial you can use to learn how to build your own Application class.